# Ios in app purchase subscription

Tags: ios

I want to sell a product with non renewing in app purchase and need to show 3 month and 6 month subscription period. For both 3 month and 6 month subscription do i need two different productid in itunes connect ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's App Store policy and would be best answered by their FAQs, forums, or customer/developer support.

Comment: need to sale more than 1000 products with 3 and 6 month subscription . Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need two different product.

**EDIT:**

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial) may help.

Comment: But i have more than 1000 of product to sale and with 3 and 6 month subscription . If i will create different productids for all it will exceed 1000 product and we can not put more than 1000 products in itunes connect

Comment: 1,000 products ?!?! what the hell ! You need to rethink your plan.

Comment: its some like exam papers and books . So i have more than 1000 product. And we can not use any third party payment gate way . What shall i do ?

Comment: Do you mean 1000 different **kinds** of papers and books? A subscription means during the period, the user is able to download all the contents of the type he/she purchased. But if you do have 1000 type of contents, maybe you have to create that many product ids.

Comment: yes i have created productids in itunes connect. And once the user purchase some particular product,my server will send all the exam papers in json format . Hope this is what you have mentioned as download ?